# using a jquery sortable/drag and drop on a select input

Tags: php, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm searching about drag and drop a select input like in my code below : 
I'm using jquery-ui with a bootstrap-multiselect libray on the select inputs.
with the .sortable, i'm able to drag and drop and sort the div draggable when i'm on col-sm-xx and plus, but in xs size, i would like to set the label in the select input, and gain place in my screen in hiding the label.
But it the sortable work only on the label, not on the select input, and i have to drag the two together.
I tried different ways and search but no one is working actually.

thanks for your returns :)

html :

```
<div id="div_sel_origine" class="panel-body dragto2 dragto3">
    <div class="draggable form-group col-sm-12 col-sm-6 no-padding">
        <label class="hidden-xs">select title</label>
        <select class="dropdown_filtre">
            <option value="1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="2">Value 2</option>
            <option value="3">Value 3</option>
            <option value="4">Value 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

js :

```
$("#div_sel_origine").sortable({
    connectWith: "#div_sel_colonne, #div_sel_ligne",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    items: "div.draggable",
    cursor: "grabbing",
    cursorAt: {
        left: ($(".draggable").innerWidth() / 2),
        top: ($(".draggable").innerHeight() / 2)
    },
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: With a "Hello" Before, it's better, but it doesn't seem to let me say hello in Edit mode, sorry

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. It's not clear what you're asking or where the problem is.